# No update version shown up for nuget even while two assemblies have different versions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am new to nuget and but realized that my recent ASP.net MVC4 project already included it so I also added packages to other projects of that solution. But that was curious; now I had two versions of Json.Net

- v. 4.5.6 within the ASP.net MVC project
- v. 5.0.6 within any other project

So what says the nuget docs... OK then, lets update. I opened the Package Manager Console, chooses the  ASP.net MVC project and typed `Get-Package -updates` with the result

> No package updates are available from the current package source.

Which is the `NuGet official package source`

A look at the different packages.config showed me:

**ASP.net MVC project**

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**other project**

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
```

So where am I wrong. Why didn't I see any updates available for the ASP.net MVC project

(please note that the Newtonsoft.Json package is just a example, I got the same thing for the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc where it is not the major version that differs)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you uninstall the package and re-install it?  I'm wondering if you have another package with an explicit reference to 4.5.6 and nuget won't update because of that (complete shot in the dark there though!)

Comment: @daveclements Thank you very much for your response. I figured it out and added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get it updated. I opened the Solution Package Manager (*Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution*)

Now I saw many duplicated entries from which I always choose the latest version, hit the manage button and added the solution that by now used the older version. NuGet now removed the the other entries and added the new one. It seems the `Get-Package -updates` always refer to the whole the solution (try `Get-Package` it will show the packages solution wide) and there I had the latest one listed.